# Responsive padding with jQuery

Tags: jquery, click, padding

I have a problem with my code in jQuery, I've created a short code to measure the right padding to add on the top and on the bottom of an image that I couldn't add via position Absolute or Flex but It works only on the second click and not on the first one, here is the code:

```
$('.Scelta_olio').on('click', function(){
            var altezzaRecipiente = $(".Olio_non_cliccato").height();
            var altezzaOlio = $(".Olio_non_cliccato img").height();
            var paddingOlio = Math.floor((altezzaRecipiente - altezzaOlio)/2) + 'px';

            $(this).addClass('Olio_cliccato').removeClass('Olio_non_cliccato').find(".Attivazione_colonna_cliccata").delay(250).addClass("Attivata").animate({opacity: 1}, 1500);
            $('.Scelta_olio').not(this).addClass('Olio_non_cliccato').removeClass('Olio_cliccato').find(".Attivazione_colonna_cliccata").removeClass("Attivata").animate({opacity: 0}, 100);
            $('.Olio_non_cliccato .Immagine_bottiglia img').css({'padding-top': paddingOlio, 'padding-bottom': paddingOlio});
        });
```

The website that I'm talking about is this one: [www.poderinodelmadonnino.it](http://www.poderinodelmadonnino.it), the last section with the 3 diefferent bottles. As you can see with the first click the other 2 bottles that are smaller don't have the right pading but If I click on another one to open it, It all works fine.

Can someone help me?

Comment: Start by logging the variables altezzaRecipiente and altezzaOlio. You'd be surprised to see how many times the height() is not what you're expecting it to be. This can be because related to different things. Use alert or console and check the values of those two variables.

Answer (score 0):

When the page first loads, you don't have elements with the class `Olio_non_cliccato` so the `height()` returns `null`.

You set the classes afterward so on the second click, you get the correct height of your elements.

In order to fix this, your elements need to have the class `Olio_non_cliccato` when the click executes.

Here's what you can do (didn't test it and might not work because of your delays and animations)

```
$('.Scelta_olio').addClass('Olio_non_cliccato').removeClass('Olio_cliccato');
$(this).addClass('Olio_cliccato');
var altezzaRecipiente = $(".Olio_non_cliccato").height();
var altezzaOlio = $(".Olio_non_cliccato img").height();
```

Comment: You were right, It was so simple yet I didn't think of it.